# Where $\mathbf S$ is the collection of all real sequences, is $K$ compact w.r.t. the metric $d_\mathbf{S}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

This is part of an old analysis prelim I'm reviewing to study for my own prelim.

We define $d_\mathbf{S}$ as:
$$
d_\mathbf{S}(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k}\cdot\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{1+|x_k-y_k|}
$$

We define $K := \{(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\}\in\mathbf S : |x_i|\leq 1\ \forall i\in\mathbb N$.

We are given that $(\mathbf S,d_\mathbf S)$ is complete. I think K is compact w.r.t. $d_\mathbf S$, but I can't see how to prove it. I can't even settle on what broad approach I think is best. Should I:

- Try to show that every sequence in K has a convergent subsequence with a limit in K,
- Try to show that every open cover of K has a finite subcover,
- Try to show that K is totally bounded?
- Use some other test for compactness?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled: $d_S(x,y)$ does not appear, in your problem as posed, to depend on $S$ at all.  Is this a typo, or what am I missing?

Comment: Consider the sequence $( (n, n, n, \cdots) : n \geq 1)$ of constant sequences. Does it have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: A metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded (verifying this is a good exercise).

Comment: @Mark: It’s just a way to identify this particular metric, distinguishing it, for example, from the metric $d_\infty$ on the same set.

Comment: @SangchulLee I see because of your comment that I had failed to include a relevant condition. I have edited the problem.

Comment: Can you check that the topology on $\mathbf{S}$ is identical to the product topology on $[-1, 1]^{\Bbb{N}}$? This is essentially because a sequence in $\mathbf{S}$ converges if and only if each coordinate converges. Then the compactness of $\mathbf{S}$ follows from Tychonoff's theorem. If you prefer a direct way, I guess you can use diagonalization argument to extract a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I wound up using a diagonalization argument -- the notation is a headache but I think it works. Thanks.